# IE workaround for semi-transparent

Tags: css

What should be the workaround in order to show in pre-IE9 the following CSS:

```
background-color: hsla(182, 44%,76%,.5);
```

Comment: Use a picture with the background you need (png have transparent) if you only wanna do it in css go for opacity see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of Microsoft's proprietary "filters" to do this:

```
background:transparent;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FA7DBDD,endColorstr=#7FA7DBDD); 
zoom: 1;
```

The hex values are in ARGB order. So convert your color to a RGB Hex value, (`#A7DBDD` in this case) and put the opacity in front (0.5 is 7F in hex) like this: `#7FA7DBDD`

This would be best done, of course inside an IE specific stylesheet, perhaps  using conditional comments.

Comment: That's works. what I did is to take your rules and place them **before** my rule, so  modern browsers use the original rule and older browsers will use yours.

Answer (score 2):

for transparent element you have more way.

for IE ->

```
filter: alpha(opacity=40);  
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=40);  
/* above line works in IE6, IE7, and IE8 */  
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=40)";  
/* above line is IE8 only */
```

and for all browsers:

```
opacity: .7;
```

But they are transparent all element , If you need transparent only any color for example background you must use 2 functions `rgba`  or `hsla` and example for them:

support : (Firefox 3+, Opera 10.1+, Chrome 2+, Safari 3.1+)

```
#rgba {  
    background: rgba(98, 135, 167, .4);  
}
```

but IE9 only support it in all version of IE and all browser support css3

```
#hsla {  
    background: hsla(207, 38%, 47%, .4);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate dom element with solid color and set the opacity ... it will work just fine :)

.bg {
   background: #000;
   filter: alpha(opacity=50);
   opacity: 0.5;
}

Comment: That means I have show this element only if the client is IE using script?